# Lighthouse, Developer Tools recommendation to "Remove unused javascript". How do I optimise /node_modules/react-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, lighthouse, google-developer-tools

I've run the performance check in Chrome's developer tools, under the Lighthouse tab. It recommends me to "Remove unused Javascript" and suggests: **…/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js** would provide a potential saving of 60.7 KiB.

I've tried removing the module entirely, but it breaks my app. There is a dependency on material-UI core files that I have installed.

I've no idea what to do next. Should I leave this and accept that it's a "necessary" bit of wasted code, or is there something else?

Comment: Hi, `.development` means you're using _React DOM_'s development package so you may want to test your app with a production build instead

Comment: Hey, if you have used `create-react-app` to set your project up, you can just use `npm run build` to create a production build, as @t3__rry mentioned.

Comment: Great spot @t3__rry and foxxycodes - I was getting too bogged down in stuff that was already fixed by the create-react-app build script. Hopefully anyone who reads this far will save themselves a lot of time :-)